# use multiple property to fetch keys from async storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I'm trying to fetch two different properties from the async storage. I just want to call one property(myKey), which calls one TextInput value by fetching(Key1) from async storage, and another property(costKey) which calls another TextInput value by fetching (Key2) from async storage.

```
//AddScreen.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, AsyncStorage, View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight, Linking } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../components/styles';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import History from '../components/History';


export default class AddScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myKey: '',
            costKey: '',
            text1: '',
            text2: '',
        }
    }
    async getKey() {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');

            const key1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key1');
            const key2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key2');
            this.setState({ myKey: key }, { costKey: key2 });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
        }
    }

    async saveKey(text1, text2) {
        key = text1 + text2;
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', key);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key1', text1);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key2', text2);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error saving data" + error);
        }
    }

    async resetKey() {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            this.setState({ myKey: value });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error resetting data" + error);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.getKey();
    }
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.formInput}
                    placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"
                    value={this.state.myKey}
                    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ text1: value })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.formInput}
                    placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"
                    value={this.state.costKey}
                    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ text2: value })}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.saveKey(this.state.text1, this.state.text2)}
                    title="Save key"
                />
                <Button
                    style={styles.formButton}
                    onPress={this.getKey.bind(this)}
                    title="Get Key"
                    color="#2196f3"
                    accessibilityLabel="Get Key"
                />
                <Button
                    style={styles.formButton}
                    onPress={this.resetKey.bind(this)}
                    title="Reset"
                    color="#f44336"
                    accessibilityLabel="Reset"
                />

                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Stored key is = {this.state.myKey}//Fetch 1 TextInput value
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Stored key is = {this.state.costKey}//Fetch 2 TextInput value
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

please suggest me, that how to call two different property separately by taking my example.

I try to improve my code as suggested but seems error:

`Error:`  Invariant Violation: Invalid argument passed as callback, Expected a function. Instead received; [object Object]

```
/AddScreen.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, AsyncStorage, View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight, Linking } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../components/styles';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import History from '../components/History';

export default class AddScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myKey: '',
            costKey: '',
            text1: '',
            text2: '',
        }
    }
    async getKey() {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');

            const key1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key1');
            const key2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key2');
            this.setState({ myKey: key }, { costKey: key2 });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
        }
    }

    async saveKey(text1, text2) {
        key = text1 + text2;
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', key);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key1', text1);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key2', text2);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error saving data" + error);
        }
    }

    async resetKey() {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            this.setState({ myKey: value });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error resetting data" + error);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.getKey();
    }
    async handleChange(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value })
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.formInput}
                    placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"
                    value={this.state.myKey}
                    onChangeText={(value) => this.handleChange({ text1: value })}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.formInput}
                    placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"
                    value={this.state.myKey}
                    onChangeText={(value) => this.handleChange({ text2: value })}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.saveKey(this.state.text1, this.state.text2)}
                    title="Save key"
                />
                <Button
                    style={styles.formButton}
                    onPress={this.getKey.bind(this)}
                    title="Get Key"
                    color="#2196f3"
                    accessibilityLabel="Get Key"
                />
                <Button
                    style={styles.formButton}
                    onPress={this.resetKey.bind(this)}
                    title="Reset"
                    color="#f44336"
                    accessibilityLabel="Reset"
                />

                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Stored key is = {this.state.myKey}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Stored key is = {this.state.costKey}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Please suggest what I had done wrong in this above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my component, which I am trying to get 'Key' and 'Key2' with 2 properties myKey' and 'costKey', when calling in TextInput, I used wrong setState() in both the getKey() and resetKey().

Here is the link with the suggested answer of my question: 
****[[Get key from async storage with 2 properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568386/get-key-from-async-storage-with-2-properties/53570272#53570272])****.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new function (along with resetKey and componentDidMount) say `updateValue` which will be use as `onChangeTextHandler`.

That function will do both - set item to local storage and perform setState.

```
export default class AddScreen extends Component {

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.getKey();
    }

    async handleChange(key, value) {
        this.setState({ [key]: value })
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

                <TextInput
                    ...
                    onChangeText={value => this.handleChange('text1', value)}
                />
                <TextInput
                    ...
                    onChangeText={value => this.handleChange('text2', value)}
                />
     ...


        )
    }
}
```

Comment: updated answer. Keep in mind that I didn't actually run that code, but it should give you a good idea of that to do

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: Thanks to suggesting to me, but it not worked. And now I got my answer.

Comment: If you have the answer to the question you should post it here so another person that has similar question will find it and will use it as a guide. I am curious myself actually how you resolved this.